# JavaScript ,RegExp to accept comma

Tags: javascript

could you please help me on regExp to match this kind of string
contains comma"," can be there for 0 Or 1 or 1..,  ( 12,000,000 )OR(12,000) OR(120,000)  and it is there, must be followed by a number.

Thank you so much for your kind help

I have tried like this

```
/^\d+[,]*\d+/
```

but it accepts the comma even if there is no number followed it,
like this 767567,7567,768,8768,

Comment: sorry, should be like this 12,000,000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* do this, but it seems quite an odd requirement:

```
/\d+(?:,\d+)*/
```

That's at least one digit, followed by zero or more combinations of a comma followed by at least one digit.

You might want "beginning of string" and "end of string" anchors on it, it depends on what you're doing:

```
/^\d+(?:,\d+)*$/
```

---

If you want to require that digits after a comma be in groups of three:

```
/^\d+(?:,\d{3})*$/
```

(That's the version with anchors.)

Comment: if I want to include the Dot"."  , I want to match string like this 12,000.00 , so if there is a dot , must appear only once and followed by 2 digits.

Comment: @MUBARAK: It's the same principle as the above: A conditional non-capturing group, in this case using `?` (zero or one of the thing before) rather than `*` (zero or more of the thing before).